# Recognize a command from an audio stream

Tags: python, audio, speech-recognition, google-now

I'd like to create an application that monitors the audio stream coming in from my microphone and looks for a "magic word" to activate a command.

I want to do something similar to what Google does in their Google Now Android application, which listens for the "Ok Google" words and then activates vocal searches.

Is there any library that already implements what I need?

I'd like to deploy my application on a Raspberry PI, so probably what I need is a Python library, but I'm open to use other programming languages.